# How to horizontally align textblocks within a stackpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock

I have a group of textblocks that are located within a stackpanel.  There is no options to horizontally align the content of the textblocks.  How do I horizontally align these columns to 'center' without hacking the margins?

[image]

Here is the xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding RowColor}" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerNumber}" Padding="5" Width="50" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerName}"  Padding="5"  Width="200" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Points}"  Padding="5"  Width="50"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fouls}"  Padding="5" Width="50" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Rebounds}"  Padding="5"  Width="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `TextAlignment`?

Something like:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding RowColor}" >
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerNumber}" Padding="5" Width="50" TextAlignment="Center" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerName}"  Padding="5"  Width="200" TextAlignment="Center" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Points}"  Padding="5"  Width="50" TextAlignment="Center"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fouls}"  Padding="5" Width="50" TextAlignment="Center" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Rebounds}"  Padding="5"  Width="50" TextAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Well that was an embarrassing waste of time.    Thanks.  I'll accept the answer when the time limit expires...